# How to get all items in a list of strings in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I got the following code:

```
import re       
dump_final = re.findall(r"\btext=[\w]*", dump5)
```

Which returns a list, e.g. `['Apple', 'Banana', 'Lemon']`.

It turns out that I need to get all the elements of this list and call another function using those elements.

To scan the whole list I used:

```
for index in range (len(dump_final)):
    # Another function that opens the apps are listed in dump_final
    devM.goToApp(dump_final[index])
```

But it returns the characters one by one. I need `'Apple'`, not `'A', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e'`.

How can I get them using a loop?

Thank you.

Comment: What is in the list dump_final before the for loop?

Comment: [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '63', ' ', '14', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'Apps ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'Video ', 'Music ', 'Camera ', 'My Files ', 'Contacts ', 'Phone ', 'Email ', 'Gallery ', 'S Planner ', 'Memo ', 'Settings ', 'Messages ', 'Play Store ', 'Flipboard ', 'Router ', 'Dropbox ', '99Taxis ', 'Whoscall ', 'Outlook ', 'Detran', ' ']

Comment: basically some junk with spaces and some apps names

Comment: So you want to get a list of non-empty strings out of this list, right?

Comment: [I edited my question]
Yes. I want to get rid of empty strings and scan all those itens using a loop (Camera, My Files) and call another function that find this app... but when I use a loop it reads the list character by character.

Comment: Your original code worked: https://repl.it/C2Y9/0 and your new code would do the same. As you describe it, `lista` must be a string, not a list. And your rephrased question in the comments is a completely different question, filtering out empty list items. `lista = [item for item in lista if item]`.

Comment: You need to provide more information, there is nothing that shows how `dump_final` becomes `lista`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you get your list, but if you have a list:

```
dump_final = ["Apple", "Banana", "Lemon"]
```

It is more pythonic to do this:

```
for d in dump_final:
    devM.goToApp(d) # Another Function that opens the apps are listed in dump_final
```

There is no need to index.  Python iterates over each element for free